# Como transformar o campo de subtração entre datas no python em int?

Tags: python, pandas

Olá tenho o seguinte código que transforma uma data "brasileira" em data padrão:

```
df2['Start_Date'] = df2['Start_Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
df2['End_Date'] = df2['End_Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
df2['Days_Considered'] = df2['End_Date'] -  df2['Start_Date']
```

O resultado daria:

Days_Conidered

x days

Como consigo transformar essa coluna do df ('Days_Considered') em inteiro? Já que ela vai aparecer por exemplo: 9 days.
Já tentei usar int(), mas dá errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coluna `Days_Considered` é do [tipo](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) `dtype: timedelta64[ns]`. Para acessar o valor de dias como um inteiro, use `.dt.days`:

```
df2['Days_Considered'] = (df2['End_Date'] -  df2['Start_Date']).dt.days
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!!! Funcionou!